# What is the proper configuration for Eureka server on Bluemix

Tags: spring-boot, ibm-cloud, netflix-eureka

I've tried to follow the instructions for setting up microservices with Spring and Bluemix using Netflix's Eureka for discovery of the services. The bootstrap.yml follows the instructions at [spring.io/blog](https://spring.io/blog/2015/01/20/microservice-registration-and-discovery-with-spring-cloud-and-netflix-s-eureka)

The discovery is not working.  The runtime error log has the following:

```
15/2/2016 08:26:11  OUT App Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    15/2/2016 08:26:11  OUT App at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0-internal]
    15/2/2016 08:26:11  OUT App at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0-internal]
    15/2/2016 08:26:11  OUT App at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0-internal]
    15/2/2016 08:26:11  OUT App at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0-internal]
    15/2/2016 08:26:11  OUT App at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0-internal]
    15/2/2016 08:26:11  OUT App at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:117) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar!/:4.5.1]
    15/2/2016 08:26:11  OUT App at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:177) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar!/:4.5.1]
    15/2/2016 08:26:11  OUT App at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:144) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar!/:4.5.1]
    15/2/2016 08:26:11  OUT App at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:131) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar!/:4.5.1]
    15/2/2016 08:26:11  OUT App at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.tryConnect(DefaultRequestDirector.java:611) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar!/:4.5.1]
    15/2/2016 08:26:11  OUT App at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:446) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar!/:4.5.1]
    15/2/2016 08:26:11  OUT App at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.doExecute(AbstractHttpClient.java:882) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar!/:4.5.1]
    15/2/2016 08:26:11  OUT App at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:117) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar!/:4.5.1]
    15/2/2016 08:26:11  OUT App at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:55) ~[httpclient-4.5.1.jar!/:4.5.1]
    15/2/2016 08:26:11  OUT App at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:173) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.jar!/:1.19]
    15/2/2016 08:26:11  OUT App ... 19 common frames omitted
    15/2/2016 08:26:11  OUT App 2016-02-15 08:26:11.968  WARN 29 --- [nfoReplicator-0] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_MFERESTSERVER/968a9f4f59be49cb9b395db8d4228e59 - registration failed java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    15/2/2016 08:26:11  OUT App com.sun.jersey.api.client.ClientHandlerException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    15/2/2016 08:26:11  OUT App at com.sun.jersey.client.apache4.ApacheHttpClient4Handler.handle(ApacheHttpClient4Handler.java:187) ~[jersey-apache-client4-1.19.jar!/:1.19]
    15/2/2016 08:26:11  OUT App at com.sun.jersey.api.client.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter.handle(GZIPContentEncodingFilter.java:123) ~[jersey-client-1.19.jar!/:1.19]
    15/2/2016 08:26:11  OUT App at com.netflix.discovery.EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.handle(EurekaIdentityHeaderFilter.java:27) ~[eureka-client-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    15/2/2016 08:26:11  OUT App at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.handle(Client.java:652) ~[jersey-client-1.19.jar!/:1.19]
    15/2/2016 08:26:11  OUT App at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.handle(WebResource.java:682) ~[jersey-client-1.19.jar!/:1.19]
    15/2/2016 08:26:11  OUT App at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource.access$200(WebResource.java:74) ~[jersey-client-1.19.jar!/:1.19]
    15/2/2016 08:26:11  OUT App at com.sun.jersey.api.client.WebResource$Builder.post(WebResource.java:570) ~[jersey-client-1.19.jar!/:1.19]
    15/2/2016 08:26:11  OUT App at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.makeRemoteCall(DiscoveryClient.java:1562) ~[eureka-client-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    15/2/2016 08:26:11  OUT App at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.makeRemoteCallWithFollowRedirect(DiscoveryClient.java:1460) ~[eureka-client-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    15/2/2016 08:26:11  OUT App at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.makeRemoteCall(DiscoveryClient.java:1443) ~[eureka-client-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    15/2/2016 08:26:11  OUT App at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.makeRemoteCall(DiscoveryClient.java:1394) ~[eureka-client-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    15/2/2016 08:26:11  OUT App at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.register(DiscoveryClient.java:879) ~[eureka-client-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    15/2/2016 08:26:11  OUT App at com.netflix.discovery.InstanceInfoReplicator.run(InstanceInfoReplicator.java:103) [eureka-client-1.3.8.jar!/:1.3.8]
    15/2/2016 08:26:11  OUT App at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0-internal]
    15/2/2016 08:26:11  OUT App at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0-internal]
    15/2/2016 08:26:11  OUT App at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0-internal]
    15/2/2016 08:26:11  OUT App at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0-internal]
    15/2/2016 08:26:11  OUT App at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0-internal]
    15/2/2016 08:26:11  OUT App at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0-internal]
    15/2/2016 08:26:11  OUT App at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0-internal]
    15/2/2016 08:26:11  OUT App Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    15/2/2016 08:26:11  OUT App at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0-internal]
    15/2/2016 08:26:11  OUT App at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source) ~[na
```

My feeling is that there has been some update in the VCAP so I include it

```
System-Provided:
{
 "VCAP_SERVICES": {
  "user-provided": [
   {
    "credentials": {
     "password": "xxxxxx",
     "port": "10336",
     "uri": "xxxx10.dblayer.com",
     "user": "xxxxx"
    },
    "label": "user-provided",
    "name": "MongoDB by Compose-w9",
    "syslog_drain_url": "",
    "tags": []
   },
   {
    "credentials": {
     "uri": "http://eurekaServer.mybluemix.net"
    },
    "label": "user-provided",
    "name": "eureka-service",
    "syslog_drain_url": "",
    "tags": []
   }
  ]
 }
}

{
 "VCAP_APPLICATION": {
  "application_id": "xxdf3f0906",
  "application_name": "restServer",
  "application_uris": [
   "MfeRestServer.mybluemix.net"
  ],
  "application_version": "047127",
  "limits": {
   "disk": 1024,
   "fds": 16384,
   "mem": 1024
  },
  "name": "restServer",
  "space_id": "xxxxxxd89089d9",   
  "space_name": "xxxxxxxx", 
  "uris": [
   "MfeRestServer.mybluemix.net"
  ],
  "users": null,
  "version": "601cce96-5d69-4f06-9259-dadad8047127"
 }
}

User-Provided:
APPLICATION_PROFILE: mferestserver
SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE: cloud

Running Environment Variable Groups:
BLUEMIX_REGION: ibm:yp:us-south

Staging Environment Variable Groups:
BLUEMIX_REGION: ibm:yp:us-south
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced this problem while writing my own eureka server and clients as well. It is because of the configuration of the client hostname and serviceUrl. It has to be dynamic in order to be hosted on cloud

Here is running example of my Eureka server and Client on IBM Bluemix

I used following Cloud Foundry Environment variables and it worked

#### For Eureka Client

```
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://eurekaregistry.mybluemix.net/eureka/
  instance:
    hostname: ${CF_INSTANCE_IP:localhost}
    nonSecurePort: ${CF_INSTANCE_PORT:${PORT:${server.port:8888}}}
```

#### For eureka server

```
eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: false
    fetchRegistry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://eurekaregistry2.mybluemix.net/eureka/
```

#### Code repositories

- https://github.com/sanketsw/Netflix_Eureka_Client_Hello_World
- https://github.com/sanketsw/Netflix_Eureka_Server